# How can get a non-trivial i18n translation to work using Sails.js?

Tags: node.js, internationalization, sails.js, i18n-node

Using `Sails.js` version `0.10.x` and trying to get the i18n stuff to work.

I have the following in my `config/locales/en.json`

```
{
  "countries": {
    "au": {
      "name": "Australia",
      "fiatCurrency": "AUD",
      "subnationalDivisions": {
        "NSW": "New South Wales",
        "WA": "Western Australia",
        "VIC": "Victoria",
        "QLD": "Queensland",
        "TAS": "Tasmania",
        "SA": "South Australia",
        "NT": "Northern Territory",
        "ACT": "Australian Capital Territory"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My `config/i18n.js` file looks like

```
module.exports.i18n = {

  // Which locales are supported?
  locales: ['en', 'es', 'fr', 'de'],

  objectNotation: true

};
```

In my controller I am trying to retrieve the correct `subnationalDivision` name via

```
res.i18n("countries." + country + ".subnationalDivisions." + state)
```

but that just gives me `"countries.au.subnationalDivisions.ACT"`, not `"Australian Capital Territory"`

I've check with a trivial example:

Given `en.json` file containing `{ "bingo" : "sparky" }`, `res.i18n("bingo")` outputs `"sparky"`

But examples using `objectNotation` don't work despite the instructions in [the i18n-node documentation](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node).

How should I get this to work?

Comment: You can try out [l10ns](http://l10ns.org). It provides you with ICU's messageformat and it syncs your translation key for you. So you can manage your localization files more easily

Comment: I'll check it out.  In the meantime the problem I described turned out to be a bug in Sails (which I fixed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem tuned out to be a bug in Sails - it was using an older version of the `i18n` package. I found and fixed the error and sent a PR to the Sails team and it was incorporated into `v 0.10.3` of Sails. (At current writing Sails is now on 0.10.5)